# Not able copy data from ADLS gen2 to SQL Server using ADF

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am not able to copy data from ADLS gen2 to SQL Server (its not Azure SQL) using ADF.

What I have done is like this:
Created Data Set: Adls gen2 dataset  Src
SQL Server DataSet  tgt

But it doesn't allow me to choose tgt as my sink, though it lists down to choose the sink if the data set is either from (Azure SQL or Data Lake).

Comment: Hi @Vinod Kumar, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an Integration Runtime and configure the same in your SQL Server Linked Service in ADF.

SQL Server is supported as sink, you can find the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview)

As SQL Server is a different compute environment than Azure, you will have to create IR (Integration Runtime) so that Azure and SQL Server can communicate with each other.

[Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime)

Comment: thanks for your reply, so Integration Runtime is already created as i am able to create the DataSet to SQL Server and also i am able to preview the data But when it comes to create DataFlow and i choose source as DataLake data set  ADF do not let me choose Sql server data set as Sink

Comment: oh so you are using Mapping Data Flows, in that SQL Server is not supported as Sink. You can refer to below link to check available sink types:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#:~:text=A%20cache%20sink%20is%20when,times%20using%20a%20cache%20lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want create on-premise SQL Server as dataset, you must install the [Self-hosted integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) manually:

- A self-hosted integration runtime can run copy activities between a
  cloud data store and a data store in a private network. It also can
  dispatch transform activities against compute resources in an
  on-premises network or an Azure virtual network. The installation of
  a self-hosted integration runtime needs an on-premises machine or a
  virtual machine inside a private network.

If you're using Data Flow, Data Flow doesn't support self-hosted integration so that we can't use SQL Server as connector:
[image]

You must use Copy active instead.

HTH.